# Probability given $2n$ cards and $4$ aces split into two piles

Tags: probability

There are $2n$ cards now, which includes four Ace.
We split them to two piles, with $n$ cards in one pile.

Question:
What is the probability of getting 2 aces in each pile?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are fairly new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are so far; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them write their answers at an appropriate level. 

Also have a look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/75923

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total number of splits is $\binom{2n}{n}$. The number of ways that the cards can split excluding the aces is $\binom{2n-4}{n-2}$. The number of ways that the aces can split so that 2 aare in one pile and 2 in the other is $\binom{4}{2}$. Hence, the probability is $\frac{\binom{2n-4}{n-2}\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{2n}{n}}$.

Comment: I do not have the right answer, but I think your solution is right.

Comment: @henrystark This solution is correct. Another expression is $\binom{n}{2}^{2}\binom{2n}{4}^{-1}$. Essentially they are the same.

Comment: @drhab Yes, you are right. The answer is $\frac{3n(n−1)}{2(2n-1)(2n-3)}\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

There are $\binom{2n}{4}$ possibilities when it comes to the places
of $4$ aces in a pile of $2n$ cards.

There are $\binom{n}{2}$ possibilities when it comes to the places
of $2$ aces in a pile of $n$ cards.